# Retrofit2 java null pointer object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, retrofit2

Hi I am trying to parse JSON using Retrofit, save it on Sqlite and display on RecyclerView. However my app crashes when I try to open the activity.
Below is my full codes of related activity. Could you please help me with resolving the issue? 
Thank you

```
public class InventoryProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements InventoryProductListAdapter.CustomClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = InventoryProductActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private InventoryProductListAdapter mInventoryProductListAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RetrofitClient mRetrofitClient;
    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private WarehouseDatabase mDatabase;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory_product);
        configViews();

        mRetrofitClient = new RetrofitClient();
        mDatabase = new WarehouseDatabase(this);

        loadInventoryProductFeed();
    }

    private void configViews() {
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_inventory_product);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);

        mInventoryProductListAdapter = new InventoryProductListAdapter(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mInventoryProductListAdapter);
    }

    private void loadInventoryProductFeed() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(InventoryProductActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading Inventory Data...");
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.show();

        mInventoryProductListAdapter.reset();
        if (getNetworkAvailability()) {
            getFeed();
        } else {
            getFeedFromDatabase();
        }
    }

    private void getFeed() {
        Call<List<InventoryProductModel>> listCall = mRetrofitClient.getWarehouseServiceInventoryProduct().getAllInventoryProducts();
        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<InventoryProductModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<InventoryProductModel>> call, Response<List<InventoryProductModel>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<InventoryProductModel> inventoryProductModelList = response.body();

                    for (int i = 0; i < inventoryProductModelList.size(); i++) {
                        InventoryProductModel inventoryProductModel = inventoryProductModelList.get(i);
                        mInventoryProductListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } else {
                    int sc = response.code();
                    switch (sc) {
                    }
                }
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<InventoryProductModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void getFeedFromDatabase() {
        List<InventoryProductModel> inventoryProductModelList = mDatabase.getInventoryProducts();
        for (int i = 0; i < inventoryProductModelList.size(); i++) {
            InventoryProductModel inventoryProductModel = inventoryProductModelList.get(i);
            Log.d(TAG, inventoryProductModel.getName() + "||" + inventoryProductModel.getCountryId());
        }
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    private boolean getNetworkAvailability() {
        return Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(int position) {

    }
}
```

> E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   codes.bala.bmsfinal1.activity.MainActivity has leaked window
>   DecorView@52c3fcd[] that was originally added here
>                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:418)
>                        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:331)
>                        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
>                        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)
>                        at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
>                        at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:104)
>                        at codes.bala.bmsfinal1.activity.MainActivity.login(MainActivity.java:61)
>                        at codes.bala.bmsfinal1.activity.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
>                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>   I/ViewConfigCompat: Could not find method getScaledScrollFactor() on
>   ViewConfiguration D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>
> --------- beginning of crash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: codes.bala.bmsfinal1, PID: 12077
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{codes.bala.bmsfinal1/codes.bala.bmsfinal1.activity.InventoryProductActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'retrofit2.Call
>   codes.bala.bmsfinal1.iinterface.WarehouseService.getAllInventoryProducts()'
>   on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface
>   method 'retrofit2.Call
>   codes.bala.bmsfinal1.iinterface.WarehouseService.getAllInventoryProducts()'
>   on a null object reference
>                         at codes.bala.bmsfinal1.activity.InventoryProductActivity.getFeed(InventoryProductActivity.java:88)
>                         at codes.bala.bmsfinal1.activity.InventoryProductActivity.loadInventoryProductFeed(InventoryProductActivity.java:70)
>                         at codes.bala.bmsfinal1.activity.InventoryProductActivity.onCreate(InventoryProductActivity.java:46)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
>   Application terminated.

Answer (score 1):

```
getWarehouseServiceInventoryProduct()
```

method return `null`.
You should set breakpoint inside this method and check what happening (or add some logs to this method).

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. It seems like there was mistype in base url. It was telling me the link must end with " / " .